# Оптимизация вложенного запроса Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать запрос:

```
select  N,Nz
        ,Round(hz, 2) as Thick
        ,Round(pf, 3) as Weight
        ,tz,ts
        ,Round((select avg(NV1L) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG1L
        ,Round((select avg(NV1R) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG1R
        ,Round((select avg(NV2L) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG2L
        ,Round((select avg(NV2R) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG2R
        ,Round((select avg(NV3L) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG3L
        ,Round((select avg(NV3R) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG3R
        ,Round((select avg(NV4L) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG4L
        ,Round((select avg(NV4R) from tab2 where DT between tab1.tz and tab1.ts), 3) as AVG4R
from    tab1
where ts between :DateFrom and :DateTo
order by ts
```

Данный запрос выполняется около 20сек, данных там около 700 Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите подзапросы, сделайте cross join обеих таблиц, группировку по полям записи первой таблицы и групповую по записям второй. Типа

```
select t1.N
     , t1.Nz
     , Round(t1.hz, 2) as Thick
     , Round(t1.pf, 3) as Weight
     , t1.tz
     , t1.ts
     , avg(t2.NV1L) as AVG1L
     , avg(t2.NV1R) as AVG1R
     , avg(t2.NV2L) as AVG2L
     , avg(t2.NV2R) as AVG2R
     , avg(t2.NV3L) as AVG3L
     , avg(t2.NV3R) as AVG3R
     , avg(t2.NV4L) as AVG4L
     , avg(t2.NV4R) as AVG4R
FROM tab1 t1
   , tab2 t2
WHERE t2.DT between t1.tz and t1.ts
  AND t1.ts between :DateFrom and :DateTo
GROUP BY t1.ts
       , t1.N
       , t1.Nz
       , Round(t1.hz, 2) as Thick
       , Round(t1.pf, 3) as Weight
       , t1.tz
order by t1.ts
```

Comment: Я бы t1.ts первым поставил в group by, тогда отдельная фаза сортировки оптимизатору скорее всего не понадобится и будет использован результат group by

Comment: @Akina Большое спасибо. Выполнение запроса занимает 2 сек

Comment: @Mike Принято, подкорректировал. Хотя будет странно, если оптимизатор не сможет сам такое сделать. C другой стороны, выражение GROUP BY следует сформировать так, чтобы наиболее эффективно использовать существующие индексы именно для отбора и группировки, а уж сортировка достаточно компактного результирующего набора - дело десятое...